# Native OS X sandbox profile to control network access (IP/host-based)

Tags: macos, sandbox

On Mac OS X, is it possible to limit an application's accessible hosts by using sandbox-exec?

I can easily do it via a firewall app, but I would prefer to do it via the native sandbox mechanism in certain cases.

So far I've tried by using something like this in the sandbox profile:

```
(allow default)
(deny network-inbound)
(deny network-outbound)
(allow network-outbound (remote ip "10.0.1.1:443"))
```

but I get errors when I try to run sandbox-exec:

```
<snip>: host must be * or localhost in network address
```

There is no official documentation for the native OS X sandbox as far as I know, and the examples included in `/usr/share/sandbox` and `/System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles/` don't have anything similar to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `sandbox-exec` says that it is deprecated. Other mentions I've found online indicate that while Apple is unlikely to remove it, it's intended as an internal implementation detail of MacOS: subject to arbitrary change and not well-documented. The most extensive documentation I can find for sandbox-exec is [here](https://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Apple-Sandbox-Guide-v1.0.pdf), which is reverse-engineered only. Page 21 covers this topic, though is not good news:

> [network*] Controls all available network operations described below. It has no support for IP filtering, it must be localhost or * (check network filter for more information).

The closest I've been able to find is proxying particular domains to local ports, then allowing traffic to that port. (In my case, this involves starting a devpi server, then telling `pip` to use that local port.) You could try other tools like `nginx` or `mitmproxy`.

Answer (score 1):

A restriction of

> host must be * or localhost in network address

unfortunately makes sense under the limitations of the sandbox as I understand it, which is that it can control access to *devices* (network interfaces, in this case) and to nodes in the file system, but not to any great detail around what you do with them (such as which protocols, ports, or hosts a network packet is sent / connection is made to or accepted from). Simply put, using `*` means "give me access to all interfaces", and "localhost" means "give me access only to the loopback interfaces" (and the latter most likely would work with any loopback address, not just the ones specifically associated with the name "localhost").

Filtering network access to specific hosts (or protocols or ports) is the job of a firewall. Unfortunately, MacOS does not, by default, come with an outbound firewall, and even the inbound one leaves some things to be desired (I think it's possible to control on a per-app, not just per-protocol or per-host basis, and allow or block an app to/from traffic that is normally blocked/allowed? Not sure though.)

On the other hand, this is somewhat freeing. While it's obviously virtuous of you to try ensuring your app runs with the minimal possible privileges, if the platform doesn't make it easy (and you aren't building a security tool that is intended to augment the platform's security anyhow), it's reasonable to simply do the best you can and accept the limitation. If you don't want your app to accept connections from certain hosts, validate incoming connections (in the app software) before you `send` or `recv` on them. If you don't want it sending traffic to the wrong hosts, limit the hostname/IP ranges it allows itself to `connect`/`sendto` to. Such restrictions won't mean anything if an attacker achieves arbitrary code execution within the sandbox, of course, but at some point you may just have to accept that if you want to support Apple users, and Apple has made the decision to accept that risk on behalf of all its users, you have to go along with that.